# What should we write when closing a question for being too elementary/homework?

Tags: discussion, scope, closing, homework

The comments and links to used when closing an elementary/homework question. I am making it CW, feel free to edit and/or add links to related discussions.

---

Related discussions:

[The reason to close too elementary questions](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/the-reason-to-close-too-elementary-questions)

[Homework, or things that look like homework.](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209/homework-or-things-that-look-like-homework)

[Flood of homework questions](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/601/flood-of-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I. This is not a ****research-level**** question in theoretical computer science as defined in the scope and is too elementary for this site (perhaps a homework exercise). Please see []() and read the FAQ.

II. This site is for ****research-level questions**** in ****theoretical computer science****, that are likely to have short well-defined answers. "Research-level" means, roughly, questions that might be discussed between two professors, or between graduate students working on Ph.D.'s, but not usually between a professor and the typical undergraduate student. It does not include questions at the level of difficulty of undergraduate homework. You can try Math.SE (elementary math/theory) or StackOverflow (programming).

Comment: I think that this is in the right direction.  A few comments: (1) “FAQ” really requires a spot-on link to http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/235#235.  (I modified the FAQ entry a little just now.)  I do not think that new users (or even some experienced users) can reach the correct entry from just the word “FAQ”.  (2) I prefer to have a list of alternative websites somewhere on Meta and just link to it rather than including the list in a comment.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: 1. I have put the [] () for linking to a more direct place, but we can also link the word FAQ above to our FAQ. 2. It is a good idea, why don't you post a question on meta: "where to direct people (e.g. when a question is off-topic)?" and we can collect them in one place.

Comment: I started a discussion about item 2: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/631/alternate-websites-to-suggest-for-non-research-level-questions

Comment: I cringe every time I read the phrase "that are likely to have short well-defined answers." (you adapted it slightly since). First, "short" is certainly relative. In the context of this platform, it reads to me like a handful of sentences. Some of the best answers are *huge*.

Comment: As for well-defined, we have had a number of nice questions lately ([here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4662/is-it-possible-to-find-if-a-sequence-exists-in-polynomial-time-in-the-following-p), [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/finding-the-distance-between-two-polynomials-represented-as-trees)) that were not well-defined themselves (initially). Therefore, I think you state no necessary conditions for a good question there. Maybe you can think about rephrasing that a bit. Also, the bolding leaves the raised-forefinger-impression, but that might be intended.